# How to list next expected matches of a Regex

Tags: regex, code-completion

Given a Regex like this:

```
(aaa)(bbb)*(ccc|ddd)
```

Is there any way to list all the possible values that will come after a token (for example `aaa`) and will match the regex?

Of course here the answer is `["bbb","ccc","ddd"]` but look at it as a general question.

Notes:

- It's not a question of how to write a Regex.
- Regex is used only as an instruction to generate the list.
- Yes! you guessed right: one of the use cases is code-completion.
- If it cannot be done (or too complicated) for the full set of Regex let's consider a simpler subset which only includes "parenthesis ()", repartitions of "zero-or-more *", "one-or-more +" and "or |"

Comment: Seems possible, what language?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I'm looking for the algorithm. Pseudocode is fine.

Comment: There are infinite possibilities on a regex expression.  If your regex format is flat as above, then I suppose you can build a parser to tokenize it and generate all possibilities.  If it has more depth (eg. (((aaa|bbb)|c))? that would be trickier to do.